# Create a home server with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, webserver, raspberry-pi

I am a native applications for android developer, and currently I am creating an application with more than 1000 images. All this images are stored in the application and come with in the apk of the application, so I don't need a connection to the Internet.

My question is: It wouldn't be nice to store these images on a server, and then request only the images needed for the current activity in my application?
This way I would need a request, but I would spare some space because I removed the images from the project itselft.

Is a Raspberry Pi a good solution for a server with images? I never used a Raspberry Pi and my knowledge of web services is poor to. Is this a hard thing to do? Where should I start?

Comment: If this is for an app for usage by more than a very few people, the upstream bandwidth of your internet connection won't be able to handle the demand.  You need a cloud service served from a data center.  If that doesn't explain, rephrase your question and tell us about what the volume of requests for an image will be, and what the upstream bandwidth is of the network the rPi will be connected to.

Comment: Actually I forgot completly about the bandwidth of my internet. This application could have thousand's of clients (depends on his success :P), so I should forgot about the Raspberry pi server. What about buying a server online?

Comment: That's what I thought.  There's actually several ready made online services, where you can upload the asset and access via URL.  Dropbox is one, but will be pricey at that level.  While this site typically isn't for shopping your should Google "dreamobjects".  More generically Google "cloud storage"

Comment: Thank you for the head start! I'll make my search about Google cloud storage and I'll update this post if I managed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?nc1=h_ls) or [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/)

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.